# free crashing with signal SIGTRAP

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

Im writing a small console based application for the windows command line.

Im allocating memory for two arrays, `chi` and `chi_comp` like this:

```
/* allocating memory for chi */
if ((chi = (int *)malloc(cm * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error allocating %i bytes of memory.\n", lm * sizeof(int));
    return CMD_NONE;
}

/* allocating memory for chi_comp */
if ((chi_comp = (int *)malloc(cm * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error allocating %i bytes of memory.\n", cm * sizeof(int));
    return CMD_NONE;
}
```

A bit later in the code I initialize them

```
for (i = 0; i < cm; i++)
{
    chi[i] = -1;
    chi_comp[i] = -1;
}
```

and use them like

```
chi[grade] = i;
chi_comp[i] = grade;
```

and

```
if (chi_comp[i] != -1)
{
    printf(" %i ", v[chi_comp[i]][0]);
}
```

Working with them works fine but when I try to free the memory when I don't need it no more the program crashes.

```
free(chi);
free(chi_comp);
```

Debugging with gdb results the following:

> warning: HEAP[m.exe]:
>   warning: Heap block at 003518B8 modified at 003518CC past requested size of c
>
> Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
>   0x776f0b2d in ntdll!RtlpNtEnumerateSubKey ()
>      from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll

chi in this case values `003518C0` and chi_comp values `003518E8`

Comment: I think you are going out of bounds somewhere in your code, so check your counters!

Comment: `chi[grade] = i;` did you check `grade is < cm`?

Comment: @gsamaras ok i dont think so but ill double check it

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @SouravGhosh ok thats a bit embarassing now... i went out of bounds... it works now

Answer (score 2):

From the error message:

> warning: HEAP[m.exe]: warning: Heap block at 003518B8 modified at 003518CC past requested size of c

I suspect you are going out of bounds somewhere in your code, so check your counters please. What tells me that is the **past requested size of**. Make sure you read twice the error messages, they are for your own good. :)

---

Next time you post, make sure you provide a minimal example of your bitte.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852335/c-free-crashing-with-signal-sigtrap?noredirect=1#comment57444715_34852335) below the question,

it appears that, in your code, by saying

```
 chi[grade] = i;
```

you're going out of bounds. Accessing  out of bound memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).You should put a check like

```
 if (grade < cm)
       chi[grade] = i;
```